# How can we remove [Required] validator from model based on condition in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have one user model and there are 2 properties password and confirm password both are required in the registration page but not required in the edit user page. As I have used one common usermodel in both the different view.

How can I achieve this in asp.net MVC 4?

Comment: It's better not to mix models.. Otherwise, you have to ignore `ModelState.IsValid` property and check model by yourself

Comment: Use `ViewModels` in your views, not the models themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View models are, by definition, specific to the views they are serving. So, the register page should have its view model and edit profile page should have a separate view model even though they seem to have very similar properties.

In the long run, it will be more hassle making sure that the changes made to the common view model to accommodate the requirements of one view do not produce errors in the other view(s) the view model is being used for.

Keep repeating the mantra "One view model per view" helps.

Comment: This is correct.

If you're keen on the properties having the same name, extract an interface to use on the two separate models.